# Annotations in domain objects in client pull complete hibernate dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, client-server, hibernate-annotations

I want to share some domain objects between my client and server apps.

Starting with Hibernate 4, the Hibernate annotations were integrated in hibernate-core (used to be a separate jar), see http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/NoMoreHibernateannotationsModule

I would *really* prefer to stick with annotations (and not switch to xml based mapping).

At the same time I would *really* like to avoid bundling the hibernate core dependencies with the client (which will be transferred to the user via http through java web start, ideally on every startup).

Do I have to go back to Hibernate 3.x? Are these annotation dependencies needed to run the client or do I just need them to compile the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have the annotations of a class in the classpath to be able to load a class.

That said, a Hibernate entity contains collections and references to other entities. The collections are instances of Hibernate collections, and the references can be Hibernate proxies, if they're lazy-loaded. So if you serialize a Hibernate entity from the server to the client, the client will need the Hibernate jar(s) in its classpath to be able to load them.

If you want to avoid the Hibernate dependency at client-side, you should consider transferring DTOs to the client rather than Hibernate entities.

Comment: Hm yes I haven't really thought this through. DTOs seem like another thing I'd like to avoid (because of the duplication). I will first experiment with hibernate on the client classpath to get more experience with serialization of hibernate object graphs.